# wp_enqueue_script не подключает js файл

Tags: php, wordpress

```
define('S_THEME_ROOT', get_template_directory_uri());
define('S_CSS_DIR', S_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/css');
define('S_JS_DIR', S_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js');
define('S_IMG_DIR', S_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/img');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'page', S_CSS_DIR . '/page.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', S_CSS_DIR . '/style.css');

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('page', S_JS_DIR . '/page.min.js');
```

В линках показывает подключение, а на деле скрипт не работает. Со стилями все ок

Comment: В каких таких линках? Что в консоли? Нет ошибок? Что в коде страницы (Ctrl+U) - есть скрипт?

Comment: В линках т.е. в коде страницы есть подключение и ошибок никаких нет, но скрипт не работает. А просто в верстке работает.

Comment: Скрипт покажите

Comment: ну и сразу вопрос - а если точку останова поставить на первую строчку скрипта?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Вот скрипт: https://yadi.sk/d/l9OV9pn1IW-6Pw

Comment: Ну там сбилженный webpack, и кода немало. Может быть все, что угодно. Скорее всего, дело в зависимостях, т.е. в том порядке, как запускаются скрипты. Сравните порядок скриптов в верстке и на сайте

Comment: А есть какой-то вариант запустить перед закрывающим body? Через wp_enqueue_script подключается в head

Comment: Откройте же документацию, там все написано. Пятый параметр https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: А зависимости - третий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключил через

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    function register_my_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', S_JS_DIR .'/page.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    }
    add_action('init', 'register_my_js');
}
```